# How to delete a column in pandas dataframe if df[0,i] is nan?

Tags: python, pandas

I have read a number of posts on pandas data frames and have gone through the docs but had to resort to asking myself, because I could not find an answer. I'd like to delete an entire column if the first value of that column has the NaN value. I am fairly new to pandas, but I should be able to simply loop through the first row and delete a column, right? Something like:

```
for i in range(0,df.shape[1]):
    x = numpy.isnan(df[i])
    if x[0]==True: 
         del df[i]
```

But this does not work for me when the column labels are not an integer 'i'. Does anyone know of a solution or better way of doing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is close to working but is using a number from `range` for deletion rather than the column name. Try changing your loop to

```
for col in df:
    if np.isnan(df[col].iloc[0]) == True:
        del df[col]
```